# Craft 3 wont update in Laravel Valet development enviornment

Tags: database, craft3, updating, valet

I'm using Laravel Valet with Craft 3 (Craft 3.0.0-RC13) and Sequel Pro.

I can't seem to get Craft to update. I just get a warning sign and a message saying that it couldn't back up the database.

When I looked at my log file, it contained the following:

> FROM `craft_info`
>   2018-03-27 09:54:43 [127.0.0.1][1][-][error][craft\controllers\UpdaterController::actionBackup] Error backing up the database: The shell command "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/Users/richardclark/Sites/lorindafontainefarris/storage/runtime/temp/my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --single-transaction --no-data --result-file="/Users/richardclark/Sites/lorindafontainefarris/storage/backups/lorinda-fontaine-farris_180327_135443_jfivi9ibwf_v3.0.0-rc16.1.sql" lorindafontainefarris && mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/Users/richardclark/Sites/lorindafontainefarris/storage/runtime/temp/my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --no-create-info --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_assetindexdata --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_assettransformindex --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_cache --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_sessions --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_templatecaches --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_templatecachecriteria --ignore-table=lorindafontainefarris.craft_templatecacheelements lorindafontainefarris >> "/Users/richardclark/Sites/lorindafontainefarris/storage/backups/lorinda-fontaine-farris_180327_135443_jfivi9ibwf_v3.0.0-rc16.1.sql"" failed with exit code 127: sh: mysqldump: command not found
>   2018-03-27 09:54:43 [127.0.0.1][1][-][info][application] $_GET = [
>       'p' => 'admin/actions/updater/backup'

I tried adding a PATH reference to my export `PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/mysqldump` in the `.bash_profile` file, but that didn't seem to do anything. Do I have to add something to the `CraftValetDriver` file, or is my PATH reference incorrect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

I believe we were conversing via Medium yesterday on this issue.

Regarding your question, I know for a fact your PATH reference is incorrect. The path to mysqldump is never `~/.local/bin/mysqldump`; mine is located at `/usr/local/bin/mysqldump` (I'm using MariaDB).

***BUT*** since you said on Medium that you're using MySQL (instead of MariaDB or another database option), you should use this instead: `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`.

After you add that to your `.bash_profile` and either [source the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608197/4914302) or quit and relaunch terminal, `mysqldump` should be working.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if the following will help with Valet, but I ran into the same problem today with my local Homebrew dev server. Despite having `/usr/local/bin` in my PATH and mysqldump working just fine on the command line the backup task would fail.

Checking the PHP info page revealed that Apache was running with a PATH setting of `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So there’s your problem.

After trying various different approaches for setting envvars and getting nowhere I eventually found that setting the PATH via the Apache launch daemon file did the job, per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6834024/1777801) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/srayhunter/5208619).

For my setup this meant editing `/usr/local/opt/httpd/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` and adding the following within the main `<dict>` tag:

```
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
   <key>PATH</key>
   <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
  </dict>
```

After adding that and running `brew services restart httpd` my PATH finally updated and the export task started working.

Comment: Just a note, great info for future reference but the OP is not using Apache since he's working with Laravel Valet which is Nginx only.

Comment: Ah thanks, I should have checked that. I’ll leave the post up in case it helps anyone else looking to fix this error with their Apache setup.